# Number of print output lines when using fork()

Tags: c, printf, fork

Im struggling to figure this out. Under which circumstances does the following program produce a different number of lines than three?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("I am the parent!\n");
  if (fork() == 0) {
    printf("I am the child!\n");
  } else {
    printf("I am still parent!\n");
  }
}
```

My first impulse is is to say that it will only produce two lines of output when fork() fails. But can it also produce a different amount of output lines?

Comment: Under the circumstances of buffered output, which is being duplicated for child.

Comment: When `fork()` returns `-1`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Does that mean that it it could print "I am the parent\n" string two times? Once in the parent and once in the child?

Comment: Yes, that is what can (and usually) happen